Dismiss local-auth fingerprint dialog
How to dismiss flutter fingerprint dialog by default? I don't want flutter to show fingerprint dialog before an authentication.
I tried useErrorDialogs = false;, but it is not the solution of my problem. I have pin interface and I add fingerprint. I want to redirect the use first to the pin page, but if it use fingerprint and is valid then it can be authenticate but I don't want to show fingerprint dialog first.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have protected a page for example with a pin and when I want to access this page I type the pin before. Now I'm trying to add fingerprint. My problem is that when I get to the pin page the fingerprint dialog is displayed asking me to check the fingerprint. But I want the pin page to be displayed without the fingerprint dialog box, but if we put the fingerprint and it's valid, the person must be authenticated
